# Find Route Between Two Points(PushPin) - Windows Phone

Tags: bing-maps, windows-phone

I have coordinates of two different pushpins and I want to draw the route between them?

Answer (score 1):

see this example of using the directions task:

http://www.playingwith.net/2011/07/integrate-bing-maps-directions-in-your-wp7-app/